# unexpected token error in plsql procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EPS.PROCEDURE_OTE_LTE_BIDDER_REPORT 
   (
       IN P_USERID INTEGER,
       IN P_AUCTIONID INTEGER,
       IN P_REPORT_FLAG VARCHAR(3),
       OUT O_ERROR_CODE INTEGER,
       OUT OUTPUT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(100),
       IN P_LOG_USERID INTEGER
   )
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    
P1:BEGIN ATOMIC DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    
    DECLARE V_USERID INTEGER;
    DECLARE V_AUCTIONID INTEGER;
    DECLARE V_REPORT_FLAG_TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER VARCHAR(3);
    DECLARE V_COUNT_TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER INTEGER;
    DECLARE V_REPORT_FLAG_SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT VARCHAR(3);
    DECLARE V_COUNT_SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT INTEGER;
    
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT_TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER FROM EPS.TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER A 
        WHERE A.AUCTIONID=P_AUCTIONID AND A.USERID=P_USERID;
    
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT_SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT FROM EPS.SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT B 
        WHERE B.AUCTIONID=P_AUCTIONID AND B.USERID=P_USERID;
    
    
    
    IF P_REPORT_FLAG = 'Y' THEN
        IF V_COUNT_TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER < 1  THEN
            INSERT INTO EPS.TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER (A.AUCTIONID,A.USERID,A.QUALIFIED) VALUES (P_AUCTIONID,P_USERID,'Y');
        ELSE
            SET OUTPUT_MESSEGE = 'DATA ALREADY PRESENT';
        END IF;
    ELSE 
        IF  V_COUNT_TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER > 0  THEN
            DELETE FROM EPS.TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER C WHERE C.AUCTIONID=P_AUCTIONID AND C.USERID=P_USERID;
        ELSE
            SET OUTPUT_MESSAGE = 'NO DATA FOUND';
        END IF;    
    END IF; 
    
    IF P_REPORT_FLAG = 'Y' THEN
        IF V_COUNT_SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT < 1  THEN
            INSERT INTO EPS.SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT AA 
            (   AA.AUCTIONID,
                AA.USERID,
                AA.TENDERREPORTTYPEID,
                AA.STATUS,
                AA.CREATEID,
                AA.CREATEDATE,
                AA.UPDATEID,
                AA.UPDATEDATE
            ) 
            VALUES 
            (
                P_AUCTIONID,
                P_USERID,
                103.
                'A',
                P_LOG_USERID,
                CURRENT TIMESTAMP,
                NULL,
                NULL
            );
        ELSE
            SET OUTPUT_MESSEGE = 'DATA ALREADY PRESENT';
        END IF;     
    ELSE  
        IF  V_COUNT_SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT > 0  THEN
            DELETE FROM EPS.SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT  CC WHERE CC.AUCTIONID=P_AUCTIONID AND CC.USERID=P_USERID;
        ELSE
            SET OUTPUT_MESSAGE = 'NO DATA FOUND';
        END IF;        
    END IF; 
    
    
 END P1
```

I am getting this error

```
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "Y PRESENT'".  Expected tokens may include:  "
  END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.85
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "Y PRESENT'".  Expected tokens may include:  "
  END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.85
  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "Y PRESENT'".  Expected tokens may include:  "
  END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.85
  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "Y PRESENT'".  Expected tokens may include:  "
  END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

Comment: I know PL/SQL but not DB2. Is there an Oracle PL/SQL emulation mode? The code above isn't PL/SQL, but then the error messages aren't what you'd get in Oracle from that code either, so it's not clear what this is.

Comment: this is db2 error.can u see the if else condition is right or not?

Comment: P1: Begin is not required here as there seems to be only one Begin within the code so simply replace the P1:Begin with Begin and replaec  the End P1 with End; and at the last add terminater as / (slash)

Comment: An example of a PL/SQL procedure in IBM DB2 is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCJDQ/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053844.html) (although the document bizarrely refers to a "PL/SQL Schema").

Answer (score 1):

It helps to properly use a syntax editor that understands SQL, and take more care with checking your code.  A good SQL editor may highlight your mistakes before you try to compile, as would any code review.

On a separate note, you should understand the difference between ANSI SQL PL  and Oracle PL/SQL. Your code seems to use ANSI SQL PL syntax, although your mistakes may be mistakes for any flavour of SQL.

Here are some of the obvious syntax mistakes in your code (there may be others):

- On the line `INSERT INTO EPS.SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT AA`  , the `AA` should be omitted.
- For the same insert statement you have `103.`,  when you might mean `103,`.
- For the line `INSERT INTO EPS.TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER (A.AUCTIONID,A.USERID,A.QUALIFIED)`  you probably mean instead
  `INSERT INTO EPS.TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER (AUCTIONID,USERID,QUALIFIED)`
- The same mistake is present for the line with `INSERT INTO EPS.SELECTIVEUSERWISETENDERREPORT` (do not qualify the column names).
- For the line  beginning `SET OUTPUT_MESSEGE =`  you probably mean `SET OUTPUT_MESSAGE =`, and this typo is present on other lines.

Comment: but i am getting error in this line of code after resolving wht u said.                                     IF P_REPORT_FLAG = 'Y' THEN
  IF V_COUNT_TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER < 1  THEN
   INSERT INTO EPS.TECHNOCOMMERCIALQUALIFIEDCUSTOMER (AUCTIONID,USERID,QUALIFIED) VALUES (P_AUCTIONID,P_USERID,'Y');
  ELSE
   SET OUTPUT_MESSAGE = 'DATA ALREADY PRESENT';
  END IF;

Comment: Do not use comments for asking new questions. Follow the advice to use an editor that understands SQL and find your mistakes that way.

Comment: sorry mate i didnt find any solution using sql editor